# Retrieving Custom Parse User Variables

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am creating an app which uses Parse. I have set up a user sign up and login. I have the username and password options all figured out, but I want a third option. This is going to be a string called "school"

```
  user["school"] = "Your School Here"
```

and it is created. I am having trouble accessing that from the current user in another class.

I need to have it as a string, so I can eventually have a PFQuery similar to

```
query.whereKey("PFObject.school", equalTo: currentUser["school"])
```

but I am not exactly sure the syntax that I would choose. If any other information is needed, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the object to a String as below:

```
query.whereKey("school", equalTo: currentUser!["school"] as! String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
query.whereKey("school", equalTo: currentUser["school"])
```

You don't need "PFObject.school". Just "school".

Comment: I tried this, however it is saying "Cannot invoke 'whereKey' with an argument list of type '(String, equalTo: AnyObject)'" Any thoughts on how to fix this? Or how to convert the school variable in the user class to a string?